# Why does mesh behave like mirrored in Edit mode without Mirror modifier?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, mirror

This is probably a very simple question, but the Mirror modifier keeps mirroring my model though i've applied/deleted it.

I read somewhere that I have to disable symmetry lock, but I'm assuming that only works in Sculpt mode which I'm not using because I'm trying to make a low-poly model. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening because I've done it before and I didn't face any problems.

If i can get some help that would be great!

Comment: Please post your .blend so it's easier to diagnose the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be this "X mirror":

[image: screenshot of X-mirror location]

You find that in Edit mode, on the *Toolshelf* (press <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle visibility), under the *Options* tab.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you very much!!