# Mesh mirror itself without a mirror modifier

Tags: mirror

as the title says "Mesh mirror itself without a mirror modifier".
I had a mirror modifier on but not anymore but the mesh keeps mirror itself and i don't know what is causing it, in my modifiers tab i only have and armature and subdivision modifier. Any idea what is causing it?
I have applied the mirror but the problem is that any new change i make it mirror it

[image]

My english is not that good sorry

Comment: I don't have auto mirror and i tried older versions of my model that had the mirror on, i apply it and it keeps happening the same

Comment: I wouldn't care if it wasn't because i want to make some shape keys

Comment: A cache folder/file lurking somewhere perhaps?  In the project folder or Blender's temporary folder?  Usually named "Blender_Cache" or similar.  Save & exit the project, delete any cache files/folders you can find, then reload.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does mesh behave like mirrored in Edit mode without Mirror modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52844/2217)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have enabled the ["*X mirror*" option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh_options.html), which is an Edit mode option rather than a modifier. It's located in the tool shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) of the viewport under the "*Options*" tab. The first one here:

[image]